# How does one join a varchar to an integer

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

For my homework, I have been given the problem where I need to write a query to join the following two tables to give me an output table like below:

```
     select order_number, Menu_Items
     from d.orders
     join d.menu as m
     on order items = menu items
```

Although I feel this is the correct approach I believe it needs either the 'cast' or 'convert' function for it to work as the a number of items can be ordered in the any order made (ie having two hamburgers). And the challenge comes when I need to associate a string to each item being ordered.

I get the error like:

```
    operator does not exist: integer = character varying[]
      Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
      Position: 438
```

I understand that I am trying to join first an integer to a variable character and second associating a string to the variable characters.

My desired solution might look something like:

```
       order_no . order_items   
       101      . hamburger, hamburger, fries, drink
       102      . hotdog, onion rings, drink
```

The tables that i am starting with would look like:

```
               ORDER TABLE
       order_number . order_items
           101      . 1,1,2,3
           102      . 5,4,3

                 MENU TABLE
          menu_item  . menu_items_number
       hamburger     .   1
       fries         .   2
       drink         .   3
       onion rings   .   4
       hot dog       .   5
```

Any help, tips, pointers, or suggestions would be much obliged.This is my first time asking a question here in SO. I would like to thank everyone for answering others questions, which have help me much in previous problems and delayed my first question until now.

Comment: Add some sample table data, as formatted text, producing the expected result.

Comment: As a general advice, If you need to do cast, your database design probably needs some adjustments.

Comment: is `order_items` from `ORDER TABLE` of type `varchar`. Can you provide table definitions - like `create table` queries - that way everyone can call it, and test. Also can you change the tables?

Comment: Storing a list of anything in a column is a sign that your database doesn't follow "normalization" rules. There can occasionally be good reasons for this, but in this case it is the cause of your problem, so you might want to read up on that.

Comment: You should really work with a bit more attention to detail: standardise singular/plural and capitalisation in names (not "order_number" and "Menu_Items"), don't post code that is impossible to run in questions ("order" should be "orders") etc.

Comment: Is the table structure you've given defined that way as part of the question you're answering? It's bad design to have it the way you've given: the relationship between menu items and orders is many to one: Each order can have any number of menu items. Normally you would handle this by having an intermediate table, like OrderMenuItems, that would have OrderID and MenuItemID, with one record per item in the order (i.e., OrderID would appear once for each item in the order)

Comment: @MattW.   Duely noted i will be more precise in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join table:

```
CREATE TABLE orders_items (order_id integer NOT NULL, item_id integer NOT NULL);
```

Which will allow you to get the items:

```
SELECT orders.id, orders_items.item_id FROM orders LEFT JOIN orders_items ON orders.id = orders_items.order_id;
```